# Laravel 4 - Pattern Based Filter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have the following filter:

```
Route::filter('security', function()
{
   //do security checks
   //send to my gateway controller and test() method

});

Route::when('/gateway', 'security');
```

The above does not seem to work, where am I going wrong?

1. What should I put inside the filter to load my test method in my gateway controller?
2. How can I test that the call is an ajax call using:

   Request::ajax()

Answer (score 0):

In order to make this code work you need to have a route `/gateway` created

```
Route::filter('security', function()
{
    if(Request::ajax()) 
    {
        //do security checks
        return Redirect::action('GatewayController@test');
    }

});
Route::when('gateway', 'security');
Route::get('/gateway', 'GatewayController@test');
```

Note that the slash `/` has been removed in `Route::when('/gateway', 'security');`.
This is because the Router adds a slash when checking registered patterns against the path info for the current request